# Change image property VS Alpha property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a "simple" question.
For this scenario, when a UIButton/UIImage could have this two states: On/Off, Activate/desactivate, etc, and maintain the touch enable

[image]
[image]

What is better, change the **image value** or the **alpha property**, if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the alpha property you could animate the transparency of the image you already have.

If you'd like a more elaborate animation then you could specify a set of images for the animation frames.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly, but the performance difference would be negligible. If you could get the exact same result using only the alpha property, it would require one less image asset in your project and that would be the biggest benefit here.